# Replace a single word continuously on every page with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, dom-traversal, text-manipulation

I would like to create a script that changes one word to an other in a page, works on SPAs, dynamically loaded content and in any humanly readable place: textNodes of most tags and attributes that are visible.

The best I could come up with is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hurr-durr
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  durr hurr
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.title = document.title.replace(/AAA/g, 'BBB');
    replaceInText(document.body, "AAA", "BBB");
    setInterval(function() {
        document.title = document.title.replace(/AAA/g, 'BBB');
        replaceInText(document.body, "AAA", "BBB");
    }, 10000);
})();


function replaceInText(element, pattern, replacement) {
    for (let node of element.childNodes) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                replaceInText(node, pattern, replacement);
                break;
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(pattern, replacement);
                break;
            case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
                replaceInText(node, pattern, replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

It recursively goes through the DOM finds the textNodes and does a string replace on them.

Questions i have trouble with:

1. Attributes. I have no idea what is worth replacing and what is not. Is there a list available from this exact aspect? I don't care about most metadata, aria (sorry), img alt, so replacing all attributes seem a very wasteful approach.
2. The `setInterval` for dynamic content. It works OK, but is very crude and setting the timeout too low is an obvious waste of resources, while too high makes it not replace in time sometimes. Is there - for example - an event that is cheaper to subscribe to when something enters the DOM and replace what I want in only that something?

Comment: The main "elegant" alternative to `setInterval` is a subtree MutationObserver, but those can be very expensive, especially on large sites with dynamic content. If you *need* high performance and you don't want to use polling, you might monkeypatch all methods that alter the DOM so that they get filtered through your logic first, but that's really hacky and I'm unsure of reliability. You'd also have to account for inline handlers somehow... I'd prefer the MutationObserver method, but if you need reliable high performance I guess you can't use it

Comment: @CertainPerformance this can work combined with the previous approach. Traverse and string replace the whole tree at first, wait a few seconds (for things initializing asynchronously) replace everything again when things settled (maybe 5 secs timeout) and register the observer. This prevents a lot of mutations to be triggered at first by some careless frontend library. I'm going to fiddle with it.

Comment: Why not using `mutation observer` instead of `setInterval`? https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/